# オブジェクト指向における呼び出しが連続する状態のことを何と言う？

Tags: java

オブジェクト指向において呼び出しが連続すること、別クラスを得るためにあるクラスから参照を重ね続けるような方法・現象はなんていうのでしたでしょうか？

例:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final var car = new Car();
  // final var battery = car.getEngineRoom().getBattery(); // ← これ
  final var battery = car.getBattery(); // ← こうする手がある
}
```

上のコードの正しさ的なところは緩く見てください。

Comment: 質問は意味的に同じではないですが、デメテルの法則を思い出したかったです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`car.getEngineRoom().getBattery();`

の書き方は、`メソッドチェーン`です。

> 別クラスを得るためにあるクラスから参照を重ね続けるような方法・現象

と書かれていますが、別クラスに限った話ではなくて、自分自身を返すメソッドの場合もあります。

チェーンの最後に呼び出されるメソッドも必ずしもインスタンスを返さないといけないという決まりはありません。

このようにメソッドを連続させることを`メソッドチェーン`といいます。

プログラムの美しさ的には下記のような意味合いがあります。

[流れるようなインタフェース](https://bliki-ja.github.io/FluentInterface/)

> そこで彼がとあるインターフェースのスタイルについて語ったのだが、 我々はそれを「流れるようなインターフェース（fluent interface）」と名づけることにした。 一般的なスタイルではないが、もっと評価されるべき代物だ。 おそらく例を示したほうがいいだろうから、そうしてみることにする。

> 以下は上記と同じつなぎ合わせを、流れるようなスタイルで行っている。

コード引用:

```
private void makeFluent(Customer customer) {
     customer.newOrder()
             .with(6, "TAL")
             .with(5, "HPK").skippable()
             .with(3, "LGV")
             .priorityRush();
}
```

---

このようにメソッドを連続させる書き方をよく目にするようになったときに `メソッドチェーン` という用語を目にして、なるほど、そういう名前かと思ったものです。同じ頃 `流れるようなインターフェース` という言葉も目にしましたが、こちらは、あまり浸透しなかったように思います。

Comment: 興味深い話までありがとうございます！fluent interface、初めて聞きました。後々リンク先について読ませて頂きますが、パッと見ビルダーパターンと同じようなものの話かと思いましたがそれとは別物なのでしょうか？自分が思い出したかったのはデメテルの法則でしたがご回答してくださったおかげでたどり着けました！

Comment: Builderパターンは、メソッドチェーンを使ってオブジェクトを構築するパターンですね

Comment: メソッドチェーンに関して補足すると、この技法は「デメテルの法則」と衝突します。とくに、質問者のコメントアウトコードのように、別クラスの別クラスの…とチェーンするのはアンチパターンに片足をつっこんでます。良いメソッドチェーンはデータ構造として適切に設計された、C#のLINQ/JavaのStream、jsのPromiseパターンのような戻り値が一定のクラスやコレクションなど、一連の操作を追加して何度でもチェーンできる構造など（「閉じた操作」やその考え方のあるもの）を持つものだといわれています。

Comment: いわゆるモナドのようなメソッドチェーンが美しいと考えることができそうですね。例にあげたページは、ビルダーパターンのようにメソッドチェーンが使われているだけで、メソッドチェーンそのものは、単純にメソッドがチェーンしたときにそう呼ばれるというだけです。